# Initializing a static Class variable known at compile time in Java

Tags: java, class, reflection

I want to initialize a static Class variable in Java:

```
public class NumberExpression {
    private static Class numberClass = Class.forName("java.lang.Number");
};
```

The above code segment doesn't work because `Class.forName` throws a `ClassNotFoundException`.  Something like `new Integer().getClass()` won't work because `Number` is an abstract class.

I suppose I could wrap `Class.forName` around a static method that handles the `ClassNotFoundException`, but is there a more elegant/standard way of getting what I want?

Edit:

(class "Number" changed to "java.lang.Number")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you do :

```
private Class numberClass = Number.class;
```

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't work because the class `Number` doesn't exist. What you meant was `java.lang.Number`.

You could try something like:

```
public class NumberExpression {
    private static Class numberClass;
    static {
        try {
            numberClass = Class.forName("java.lang.Number");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

But this just makes sense when the class that you are trying to load is dynamic, otherwise you could use the class it self (i.e. `Number.class`)

Comment: Yes, you're right. But even after I change it, the compiler still complains that the exception needs to be caught.

Comment: @math4tots: Then catch the exception!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth How? it's a static variable, so I don't know where I should set it. From what I understand, I don't think I can catch exceptions in a class body...

Comment: @math4tots: please take a look into my update ;) What I'm doing there is creating a static block, and within this static block the `numberClass` is set.

Comment: That is really cool that you can do that. However I think Dalkitsis had exactly the solution I needed.

Comment: As commented in the answer, it just makes sense if it is loaded dynamic (for example a string read from configuration file and so on) ;)